# Non-observant Jew making kiddush

Tags: halacha, shabbat, heterodox, kiddush, motzi-yedei-chovato

Can a Jew who does not observe Shabbat say kiddush for others?

Comment: Is he or she intending to fulfill the obligation of Kiddush for themselves?

Comment: Is the wine Mevushal?

Comment: See also http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/56913

Answer (score 4):

I attended a halacha shiur when I was in yeshiva that addressed this issue. I believe that the posek that my rav was quoting was Rav Ovadiah Yosef zt"l; however, unfortunately, I lost my notes from that shiur, so I cannot confirm that this is correct.

He said that, in general, one should not hear kiddush from someone who is *mechalel shabbat*; however, if a *kibbud av* scenario comes up (i.e. non-religious father wants to make kiddush), one may be lenient in such a scenario as long as the father believes that God exists, even if he does not follow halacha. In this scenario, he should use wine or grape juice that is mevushal.

If someone finds himself in a situation where someone who is *mechalel shabbat* or who does not believe in God is making kiddush, he can simply say kiddush quietly to himself along with the person making the bracha.

Comment: But he doesn't have a kos

Comment: @user6591 who doesn't have a kos? Remember not to use this site for practical halachic advice. In any event, why does it matter? Any large-enough cup will do.

Comment: Or you can say kiddush on the slice of challah you get.

Comment: @Daniel the 'son' in your case has no cup in front of him. He can mumble kidush all he wants but it would be strange to say that it has anything to do with the cup in front of the father. And even if it did he would have to drink a rov riviis which is not a common amount for the mikadesh to pass to him.

Comment: @user6591 see DoubleAA's comment

Comment: @Daniel i saw that and its a great suggestion. But that is not at all what's implied by your words. You make it sound like his kiddush he is mumbling is on the cup. Is that what you meant?