# A Less-Observant Jew Leading Prayers

Tags: halacha, shabbat, sin, chazzan-prayer-leader, heterodox

Can a Jew who does not observe *Shabbat* act as a *shaliach tzibur* (to lead prayers on behalf the congregation)?  I know that many are lenient and find reasons to count a *mechalel shabbat* for a minyan, but I am not certain if there is a stricter standard for allowing them to lead a service and have their prayer represent other people's.  Is it relevant whether the particular service is on *Shabbat* (like that could be scoffing in a way that a weekday wouldn't)?

Inspired by [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/47974/3483).

Comment: http://www.yeshiva.org.il/midrash/27045

Comment: See also http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/27776

Comment: There are couple of articles in the Techumim series that discusses 'who is observant', the נפקא מינה being whether a community can decide who to accept into their kehilla and whether wine of non - observant jews has the same din as יין נסך. I cant remember which volumes the articles were in but they discuss relevant points in this discussion

Comment: Are they leading on Shabbat or during the week?

Answer (score 1):

There's a theoretical halachic category of someone who publicly, purposely violates the Shabbat; but practically, that's not what you'd call your average non-Shabbat-observing Jew today.

A community could certainly enact its own higher standards, but essentially it's permissible. Rabbi Moshe Shternbuch has a responsum to a small town in South Africa which has to choose a cantor for *high holidays*. Candidate A keeps a traditional Jewish lifestyle, but drives on Shabbat. Candidate B keeps Shabbat, Kashrut, etc. 100%, but is married to a non-Jewish woman. (He's a kohen, so it wouldn't help if she converted.) Rabbi Shternbuch felt that B was preferable; many other poskim feel that A is.

Comment: what's your source? Where does rabbi Sternbuch say that? Moreover, he seems to say the opposite, in that a machalel Shabbos shouldn't lead the services